# Loop - Access violation writing location 0xabababab

Tags: c++, loops

when I set the loop to iterate 10 times it works, however no matter how many iterations I set it always brings up this error on the 12 time. here is the code below.

does anyone know why this happens? or if there is a logic error in the code I am missing out on. thanks

```
string* Analyser::topFiveBuyers()
{
//set size and add buyer names for comparison.
string *calcString = new string[sSize];
int calcTotal[sSize] = {INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN};

//checks transactions
for (int i = 0; i<nTransactions; i++)
{
    //compares with arrays
    for(int j =0; j<sSize; j++)
    {

    if(calcTotal[j] < calcTotal[j+1])
    {
    int tVar = calcTotal[j+1];
    string tStr = calcString[j+1];
    int tVarTwo = calcTotal[j];
    string tStrTwo = calcString[j];

    calcTotal[j] = tVar;
    calcString[j] = tStr;
    calcTotal[j+1] = tVarTwo;
    calcString[j+1] = tStrTwo;
    }

        if(tArray[i].buyerName == calcString[j])
        {
        calcTotal[j] += tArray[i].numShares;
        break;
        }
        else
            {
                //checks if shares is great then current total then replaces
                if(tArray[i].numShares > calcTotal[j])
                {
                    int tVar = calcTotal[j];
                    calcTotal[j+1] = tVar;
                    string tStr = calcString[j];
                    calcString[j+1] = tStr;
                    calcTotal[j] = tArray[i].numShares;
                    calcString[j] = tArray[i].buyerName;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
return calcString;
```

Comment: What line does the error happen on?

Comment: Where do you get the access violation?

Comment: come on.. `calcTotal[j + 1]` will yield UB for `j == sSize - 1` since the array is of size `sSize` and the valid indices are `0` to `sSize - 1`. fix your loop over `j` by only going until `j + 1 < sSize`..

Comment: in the second if statement - the line is calcstring[j+1] = tStr

Comment: Stefan suggestion does work in this case. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2075995 please, do yourself a favour and use _std::vector_ instead of pointers and plain arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `calcString[j+1]` and `calcTotal[j+1]` and `j` is equal to `sSize-1` on last loop run. So you are going outside array bounds.